# Как передать данные введенные пользователем между страницами

Tags: php

Смотрите, есть три страницы `1.php`, `2.php`, `3.php`. В `1.php` и `2.php` есть формы, их заполняет пользователь. Потом данные, которые ввел пользователь должны отобразится в `3.php`. Но данные с форм `1.php` не отображается, их как-то прерывает `2.php`.

Как этого избежать?

Comment: Записывайте в базу, сессию или скрытые поля (на второй форме) значения с первой.

Comment: вопрос надо как-то покоректнее задавать..... Ничего же не понятно

Comment: Короче, как перекинуть данные через страницу?

Comment: Например, сохранить в сессии.

Comment: имхо лучше предевать в скрытые поля на 2.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
<form action="3.php" method="post или get">
 <input type="hidden" name="infa" value="$_POST['данные'] или $_GET['данные']">
</form>
```